# How to preserve the test data generated by pytest-django fixtures

Tags: django, pytest, fixtures

I have been looking for a way to preserve the database records generated by pytest fixtures because the fixture data should be very useful not only for the pytest but also for the acceptance test.

For example, I have pytest fixtures something like below:

```
@pytest.fixture
def employee(company):
    return Employee.objects.create(
        **{
            'company': company,
            'name': 'MyName',
            'email': 'example@example.com',
        }
    )
```

However, after the pytest finishes, I get the following result.

(Although I get 1 as a response during pytest process.)

```
user@56c27685fc50:~$ manage.py shell_plus
# Shell Plus Model Imports
from project.apps.core.models.common import Employee
Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb  2 2020, 08:37:37) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: Employee.objects.count()                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[1]: 0
```

I would appreciate if you could share some idea to preserve the fixture data.  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This sounds strange - you want the setup for your tests to survive the tests? How will the next test run? And why can't you use same fixture for your acceptance tests? Obviously I'm not getting something here...

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.
I have misunderstood the lifecycle of fixtures: each fixture is created when it is called by test methods.

Since I have prepared many fixtures, I was expecting to use the same data for the acceptance test (as maintaining both is redundant), but I have realized that use case could be unrealistic...